# Session state lost between ajax posts?

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net login page, which when initialized sets some session variables. When the user clicks login, an AJAX request is made which validates the user and sets additional session variables and returns a result to the client. The client is then redirected based on the login result. In the redirected page, I can access the session variables set when the login page was initialized (i.e. before the login) but none are present for those set during the login validation (part of an ajax call).

is this expected behaviour? Why would an ajax call generate a new session and thus cause the data to be lost?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code and also how your site is structured?

Answer (score 2):

Is the location for your ajax call in the same application space as the rest of the application??  If I remember right you can't share session information between applications.  That may be what's going on.

Comment: Its called as part of a login usercontrol which is in a separate assembly but part of the same overall site/application

Comment: Well that was worth a shot. :-)  I'd probably check to see if the session cookie is being passed in like Guffa and Crooy recommended.  Or has a work around you could just pass everything through client variables back and forth through the ajax call and then to the redirected page.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the browser sends the sends the session id along with ajax requests. If you use Firebug or something similar you can view the contents of the ajax request and check if the session id is sent along.

The session id is stored in a cookie, which (depending on options) can only be used for the same domain/host name. This could be a reason why it is not sent.

Depending on your code, I guess that if no session id was sent a new one is created.

Comment: As noted above, the session ID is consistent throughout but everything else seems to be being cleared between the login page, the JQuery Ajax POST and return!

Answer (score 0):

The session id is stored in a cookie, which is returned in the header of the response. As you are doing an AJAX call, the cookie is just part of the response. If you want to use the same session for another request, you have to get that cookie and send it along in the header of the request.

Comment: The session ID is the same between the requests. As an example, I put

Session[“test”] = “test”;

Inside the login page onLoad method.
Then in the form validation (the session ID is the same, I just checked) the value is now ‘null’. If i set it again:

Session[“test”] = “new value”;

Then when I hit my redirected page (again, same session ID),
Session[“test”] = “test” again!!!
Any ideas on whats going on? I’m confused!

Comment: @LDJ did you manage to solve this problem? I know 13 years have passed, but I am still struggling with the same issue that you had 13 years ago...